# Self-educated vs. self-taught

Tags: american-english

Is there some difference between: 
"Self-educated" and "self-taught"?

I think that "self-taught" is more convenient.

Comment: To me, "educated" suggests a kind of completion—what you would say if someone has attained the equivalent of a high-school diploma or a college degree. In contrast, "self-taught" suggests to me that a person has acquired a specific skill. For example, I acquired most of my language knowledge in the usual way—by developing a sound base in school. I am not self-educated in that regard. But I am also a self-taught computer programmer—I've never had a formal programming lesson in my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, "education" is a broad statement, encompassing all areas of learning, whereas "self-taught" is more specific to a task. E.G.:

- *Unable to attend school, she was self-educated.* I.E., in maths, French, English, physics...
- *She was a self-taught tuba player.* I.E., she taught herself that skill.

That said, the terms *might* be used interchangeably.